# Run Mocha tests from Node - 'describe' is not defined

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to run Mocha tests after, for example, an event fires from within a Node program. I'm trying to avoid using `child_process`. After reading [this](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically) wiki page, I set up my code as follows:

```
var Mocha = require("mocha");
var Reporter = require("./reporter");

var mocha = new Mocha({
    ui: "tdd",
    reporter: "spec"
});
mocha.addFile("test.js");

mocha.run();
```

Where `test.js` has a valid mocha test. But when I run this, I keep getting `ReferenceError: describe is not defined`. Why is this happening? (When I searched this problem on Google most of the solutions were about people running `test.js` with node rather than mocha.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[As per their docs](https://mochajs.org/):

> The BDD interface provides describe(), context(), it(), specify(), before(), after(), beforeEach(), and afterEach().

You have ui set to "tdd":

> The TDD interface provides suite(), test(), suiteSetup(), suiteTeardown(), setup(), and teardown():

Answer (score -1):

```
var Mocha = require("mocha");
var Reporter = require("./reporter");

*File "<ipython-input-42-669e9b71bd81>", line 1
    var Mocha = require("mocha");
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*
```

as output

> 1.describe() is not defined as it was not availabel in H2OFrame